# Fast UI for Core Audio?

Tags: iphone, user-interface, core-audio

I am currently developing an audio app with Core Audio and iOS. I need the fastest UI to trigger sound events with the lowest latency. I've testing Cocos2d (that is built on top of OpenGL) but I found the latency is still too big.

Any advice?

Thanks.

André

Comment: My advice is to accept some answers.

Comment: Sure. While reading some comments ;^)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using OpenGL ES directly, instead of Cocos2D (I have used this with less than 25 ms latency; sorry that I cannot share the code, because what I develop at work cannot be shared).

Apple's AurioTouch is a good starting point for an OpenGL interface with Core Audio support.